# Bootstrap form inline with labels above, position button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use an inline form with labels above the inputs. There is a button at the end of the line, how can I align the button to the bottom of the inputs? (Note that I do not want to use the `form-inline` class because I want the labels above in inputs)

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label>Input 1</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label>Input 2</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

I tried adding absolute positioning

```
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j27pd4nb/)

Comment: Typo error.  Its not botton but bottom.

Comment: @Leothelion good catch but still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: So you want to put the top of the button touching the bottom of the last input? What do you mean by "align the button to the bottom of the inputs?"

Comment: @Zack bottom of the buttom algined with bottom of input

Comment: You want the button on the same line as the last input then?

Comment: @user2954587 Take a look **[here](http://www.bootply.com/93481)**. It is a working example for your problem

Comment: @user2954587 check this one https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/j27pd4nb/3/

Comment: @user2954587 also keep in mind that if you want to use position:absoulte then use position:relative too or else you will get another error :p

Comment: @Leothelion I like your solution! thanks

Comment: @user2954587 your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You can use another `div` with `class="row"` below the one you have. I modified your jsfiddle to show it</del>

Edit:
Sorry I misunderstood at first here are my two solutions:
First one is to add a `label` along with button that has some dump text (for size calculation purposes) then set `visibility` of this label to `hidden`. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ut7expbo/) that shows an example. This has the downside of being not responsive which can be easily solved using other class directives.

Second is similar to your solution but fixes `div` height being 0px by manually settings it and again messes with responsiveness. [jsfiddle-2](https://jsfiddle.net/mc3uwujg/)

Comment: then the button would be on a new line, which is not what I want

Comment: @Fma this doesn't solve his Problem. He want to have the button in one line with the 2 inputs not in an extra row

Comment: not working solution.

Comment: @user2954587 please recheck updated solutions :) sorry that I got it wrong at first.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute`, and `bottom:0` from button. You need to cover the space reserved for missed label in the last column. Add `margin-top: 28px` insetad.

Answer (score 0):

The column with the button doesn't have the same height as the other columns:

[image]

As mentioned, you can do this:

```
.row .btn {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I'm not a huge fan to make a correction like this... You can use [CSS flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) with Bootstrap to make the columns inside a row have the same height, just create a class:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

And then use `<div class="row row-eq-height">` instead of `<div class="row">`.

And you can define the position of the button as you mentioned:

```
.row .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[Live Example in CodePen](http://codepen.io/ocordova/pen/kXRwYw)

Source: [Official experimental example of same-height columns using CSS flexbox](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13203)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to remove the `absolute` positioning and to make use of the `form-control-static` class. Unfortunately, in order to align it I was using an empty label which might not be the cleanest solution.

Check the code below:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label>Input 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label>Input 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label></label>
      <div class="form-control-static">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```