# using form-group with label button is getting aligned to top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4. When i use form group in below example. I am getting an issue  while aligning the save button. It is getting aligned to top. Because i don't have a label at the same level.

I tried using this example [Bootstrap form inline with labels above, position button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721589/bootstrap-form-inline-with-labels-above-position-button)

But still I need to hard code margin-top. Otherwise button will get aligned to bottom. Is there anyway , i can achieve this using pure bootstrap without overrides?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by Unit" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zones">Zones</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="zones">
          <option>Zone1</option>
          <option>Zone2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="unitname">Unit Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="unitname" placeholder="Enter the Unit Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button type="submit"  class="btn  btn-primary"><i
          class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Zone Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let zone of zones|async">
            <td>{{zone.zoneId}}</td>
            <td>{{zone.zoneName}}</td>
            <td>{{zone.status}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to wrap the button inside a `form-group` and then add classes `d-flex`
and `align-items-end` to the `col-*` div that contains it. Example:

```
<div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-end">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>Save
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Minimized Example:**

Note that `border` and `border-*` classes are just to help visualize the layout.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by Unit"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>Search
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 border border-warning">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zones">Zones</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="zones">
          <option>Zone1</option>
          <option>Zone2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 border border-primary">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="unitname">Unit Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="unitname" placeholder="Enter the Unit Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-end border border-danger">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: @Vipin Please, consider to vote-up on the answer is this helps you. Thanks!